# Android - Remove the 'flash' animation between Activities

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition, user-experience

I want to better the user experience of my app.

I have an Activity which takes a time to load, so I am creating like a fake screen before the actual screen is loaded.

The fake screen should look exactly like the new screen so that the change is not visible.

However, Android is making a "flashy" transition between the two activities, which results in a worse experience. This transition sometimes depends on the phone model.

Is there a way to prevent any kind of animation and just display the activity contents without transition or flash (black or white) ?

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom style which disables the animation:

```
<style name="noAnimation" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

And set it for your activities in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimation">
</activity>
```

or set it for your whole application:

```
<application android:theme="@style/noAnimation">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this in your xml theme:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
```

Changing the color with the color that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` will force device to not use any animation for transition.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```